# How to install hindi font in kindle 6.4.5 without rooting it?

Tags: fonts, amazon-kindle

I have Kindle whose version # is 6.4.5.
I have installed whatsapp in it. But the Hindi messages will not appear correctly , it will be shown in rectangle form. I have tried to install hindi font as mentioned below

> Before installing fonts you need to make sure that those fonts meet 
>   the minimum requirements, such as:
>
> ```
>       a. The format used is TrueType or OpenType. 
>       b. You need to have 4 variants of the files: regular, bold, bold 
>           italic, italic 
>       c. The file structure should look like this: [name]-Regular.ttf , 
>           [name]-Bold.ttf ,[name]-Italic.ttf, [name]-BoldItalic.ttf
> ```
>
> After you make sure they meet these requirements you need to take the
>   following steps in order to use your custom fonts:
>
> 1. Connect the Kindle to your PC;
> 2. Use the computer and browse the content of the Kindle and create a folder in the root of the drive : fonts;
> 3. Copy your files in that folder, following the structure given above;
> 4. Start Calibre and go to Kindle Configuration > Modify Kindle Settings;
> 5. From the Font Family, choose the fonts you need;
> 6. Save the settings and wait for the device to reboot.

But get no success.. Please can any one help me